# Comparator as a parameter for the constructor of a class

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I can't seem to find exactly how to do this anywhere. I am writing a class that takes a comparator as a parameter/argument for the constructor of a class. I want to use that to order items in a list. But I'm not sure what to do with the comparator in the new class.

- I have imported `java.util.Comparator`
- In the class declaration I said "`impements Comparator<T>`"
- I have written (`Comparator<T> c`) as the argument for the constructor of the class.

I have never used a comparator this way--I've used it as an inner class and that is it so I'm not sure how to make the compare method work in this class when I take the comparator in as an argument to the constructor.

The only things I've done that are the three bulleted items above. Anytime I try to do something with comparator I am taking in as an argument, I get an error message.

Here is the code for the constructor:

```
public class SortedList<T> implements Comparator<T>
    //value, position and array are instance variables
    //I am switching array to a List to deal with generics
    private int position;
    private Integer[] array;

    public SortedList(Comparator<T> c){
       this.position = 0;
       this.array = new Integer[25];
    }

    public void sort(Integer num){
       boolean valid = false;
       int i = 0;

       while(!valid && i < array.length-1){
          if(num.compareTo(array[i] > 0)){
            array[i+1] = array[i];
            array[i] = num;
          }else{
            i++;
       }
    }
```

The error messages I have been getting are:

- Cannot find symbol - method compareTo

I would like to be able to compare any two objects, not just integers, that was why I wanted to take a comparator as a parameter.

Comment: Can you please share your code? [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) has some constructors that expect a `Comparator` as parameter ([OpenJDK 11 sources of `TreeMap`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/TreeMap.java))

Comment: the passed argument is just an instance implementing `Comparator`, it can be passed to [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)) as any other instance of `Comparator`

Comment: if the constructor is provided the `Comparator` you then do not need to `implements` Comparator - just use it - but you haven't shown code where it could be used so that would be helpful - and if you get errors, show the error.

Comment: I just added the code--sorry it took so long, I didn't flesh out the sorting method because I can't get the comparator to work.

Comment: Errors are that it can't find the compare method.  I think the problem is that I don't know how to use the comparator in this case. I can't create an instance of the comparator (that was another error message). How do I even make it work so that I can compare two objects? In theory, I would be comparing other types of objects (that was why I wanted to take a comparator as a parameter) not just integers, I was just using that to test this out.

Comment: @kocho84 Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have and the complete error message(s) you get.

Comment: I just updated the code, I haven't gotten far because I can't get compareTo to work. I just have the constructor and part of the sort method. I will be switching this from an array to a list to deal with generics, but the only issue i'm having is i can't get compareTo to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SortedList<T>` class must not implement the `Comparator<T>` interface, because  this class is not used for comparing objects. However, it will **use** a given `Comparator<T>` instance to sort its entries. This means the classes and methods should have the following definitions:

```
public class SortedList<T> {
     // ...
}
```

The class does not implement the `Comparator<T>` interface anymore.

```
private T[] array;
```

The `array` field should be of type `T[]` since this `SortedList<T>` object is used to sort/hold objects of type `T`, not `Integer` objects.

```
public SortedList(Comparator<T> c){
    // ...
    this.comparator = c;
}
```

That's correct. The constructor receives a `Comparator<T>` instance. You should store this reference to a field so you can later use it in your `sort()` method.

```
public void sort(){
    // ...
}
```

The `Integer` argument on the `sort()` method doesn't make any sense, so delete it. Now you can use the stored `Comparator<T>` instance in your `sort()` method and call its `compare()` method to compare two objects from your stored array. A code fragment might look like this:

```
// ...
if (this.comparator.compare(this.array[i], this.array[i+1])) {
    // it should be on the left
} else {
    // it should be on the right
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question, but the only collection-ish construct in your snippet is an array of integer objects. Thus, the only sane thing to sort here is that array.

You'd need a `Comparator<Integer>` to sort that, not a `Comparator<T>`.

Once you have that, to sort that array, all you need to do is..

```
Arrays.sort(array, c);
```

Comment: Right, I have been tinkering with it trying to get it work with non-generics (like Integer) however, my real goal is to compare generics within the array, but I couldn't remember how to create an array of generics -- that was why I switched to Integer for that part.

Comment: I would also like to compare items before they go in the array that is why I'm not using arrays.sort.

Comment: You can't have an array of generics. You can have a `List<T>` though. You can sort those just the same. If you must use an array, you have to hack around some generics issues (which involves getting some warnings that you then have to suppress, and some casting); see the source code of ArrayList.java for an example.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that part of it up! I will switch to list (i knew there must be a problem with using generics and arrays based on error)... but how can I then compare two objects like this:

object1.compareTo(object2) 

with the comparator that I took in as a parameter?  Assuming I switch to list which can take generics.

Comment: comparator.compare(o1, o2)

Comment: thank you! that worked. i just didn't know how to call it. i fixed a few other things too, thank you for your help!

Comment: @rzwitserloot "can't have an array of generics"? `Arrays.asList(T...)` or `Arrays.copyOf(T[], int)`! - you cannot **create** one using `new`

Comment: I oversimplified, but the context of the question is 'use an array of T as backing array for a collection impl of some sort', which is not really an array of T, and ArrayList intentionally doesn't do it.